# Content scales outside scrollview port in Unity's UI, but only on Android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I was wondering why the content of my scrollview suddenly began scaling to be outside the viewport of my ScrollView, which had worked fine up until then.

It still worked fine on Windows and I hadn't changed anything in scripts that should cause such an effect.

I discovered the answer which I will share below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the scrollview port didn't work as intended on Android because I had ticked the boolean "disable depth and stencil" in the Android player settings. After unticking the boolean and saving the project settings the scrollview port worked as intended again.

[image]